# Apache is showing folder directory for codeigniter application

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have apache and php installed on my device, Anytime I open codeigniter application on my localhost it shows the folder directories instead of the index page, if I tried to open the application for the folder directory it returns "Direct Access is Forbidden".

But this works fine for core php but not with codeigniter.

Can anyone help me with a solution to this?

Comment: "Direct Access is Forbidden" - Do you mean "Directory"? What file are your requesting?

Comment: in your config.php I would try to set explicitly your base_url: `$config['base_url'] =  'http://yourlocalhost_alias/';` and also check my .htaccess file to see if it's redirecting correctly

Comment: Maybe you can provide the apache configuration of the web site and the url you're using to access the application and the url used by "codeigniter"

Comment: i tried something like http://localhost/folder_name/index.php and give the following error

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST in C:\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ci\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 58